# Elasticsearch - Using copy_to on the fields of a nested type

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic version 7.17

Below I've pasted a simplified version of my mappings which represent a nested object structure. One `top-level-object` will have one or more `second-level-object`. A `second-level-object` will have one or more `third-level-object`. Fields `field_a`, `field_b`, and `field_c` on `third-level-object` are all related to each other so I'd like to copy them into a single field that can be partial matched against. I've done this on a lot of attributes at the `top-level-object` level, so I know it works.

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": { //one top level object
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
                "second-level-objects": { //one or more second level objects
                    "type": "nested",
                    "dynamic": "false",
                    "properties": {
                        "third-level-objects": { //one or more third level objects
                            "type": "nested",
                            "dynamic": "false",
                            "properties": {
                                "my_copy_to_field": { //should have the values from field_a, field_b, and field_c
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "index": true
                                },
                                "field_a": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "index": false,
                                    "copy_to": "my_copy_to_field"
                                },
                                "field_b": {
                                    "type": "long",
                                    "index": false,
                                    "copy_to": "my_copy_to_field"
                                },
                                "field_c": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "index": false,
                                    "copy_to": "my_copy_to_field"
                                },
                                "field_d": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "index": true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run a nested query against that `my_copy_to_field` I get no results because the field is never populated, even though I know my documents have data in the 3 fields with `copy_to`. If I perform a nested query against `field_d` which is not part of the copied info I get the expected results, so it seems like there's something going on with nested (or double-nested in my case) usage of `copy_to` that I'm overlooking. Here is my query which returns nothing:

```json
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "inner_hits": {}, 
      "path": "second-level-objects",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "inner_hits": {}, 
          "path": "second-level-objects.third-level-objects",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {"match": {"second-level-objects.third-level-objects.my_copy_to_field": "my search value"}}  
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried adding `include_in_root:true` to the `third-level-objects`, but that didn't make any difference. If I could just get the field to populate with the copied data then I'm sure I can work through getting the query working. Is there something I'm missing about using `copy_to` with nested fields?

Additionally, when I view my data in Kibana -> Discover, I see `second-level-objects` as an available "Nested" field, but I don't see anything for `third-level-objects`, even though KQL recognizes it as a field. Is that symptomatic of an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add complete path nested, like this:

```
         "field_a": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": "second-level-objects.third-level-objects.my_copy_to_field"
          },
          "field_b": {
            "type": "long",
            "copy_to": "second-level-objects.third-level-objects.my_copy_to_field"
          },
          "field_c": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": "second-level-objects.third-level-objects.my_copy_to_field"
          }
```

Comment: I'm really annoyed to say that this worked like a charm. I had tried adding the third-level-objects portion of the path to the field, but I guess I overlooked trying it with the FULL path. Thanks for your help with this!